# vertical align text in a div - responsive to window resize

Tags: html, css

I have some vertically aligned text in a div that I want to remain vertically centered when the browser resizes. As the div shrinks with the browser, my text becomes offset towards the bottom of the div.
Any suggestions?

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdqdpyc0/) of the issue I'm experiencing.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <h1>
        Vertically aligned text
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer-wrapper {
  background: url("http://paulmason.name/media/demos/full-screen-background-image/background.jpg") no-repeat left top;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  height: 360px;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
}

.header-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Your DIV has a set height - the `h1` is always staying in the center of the DIV, but the picture doesn't always stay the full height of the DIV. Change your `background-size:cover` to see what I mean.

Comment: In adittion of @GavinThomas : or change the background with an image, by this mode, the box that contains the image with `height: auto` defined will occupy the current height of the image, so your text will be centered always.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "As the div shrinks with the browser, my text becomes offset towards the bottom of the div". You seem to have fixed heights on your divs (so it won't change height as the browser resizes), do you want the vertical alignment of the text to change with regards to the div's _width_?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser Resize your browser in my fiddle to see what I mean

Comment: Is this ok for you ? https://jsfiddle.net/vdqdpyc0/9/

Comment: @noclist Right, so the problem _isn't_ that the text is not aligned in your div, it's when the browser width is small, the background no longer fills the full height of your div.

Comment: @VincentG exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

*The text actually does center, though the background image doesn't, hence it looks like it doesn't, so here is 2 versions (fiddle use `background-size: cover`) where image centers too*

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdqdpyc0/12/)

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.outer-wrapper {
  background: url("http://paulmason.name/media/demos/full-screen-background-image/background.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  max-height: 360px;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <h1>
        Vertically aligned text
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, observe how the text doesn't remain centered in the div as the div shrinks.

Comment: @noclist It does center, though the background image doesn't, hence it looks like it doesn't .. check this fiddle, where the background image stays centered as well: https://jsfiddle.net/vdqdpyc0/12/

Comment: @noclist Updated my answer showing how also image centers

Comment: `max-height: 360px;` may not even be necessary.

Comment: @JohnB  If the OP don't want to limit it to the image, no, though I assumed that as he had that height set in his question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your background, the div is staying the same size and the text is staying centered, you background makes it seem not so. Like Gavin  said use background-size cover.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't actually that your text isn't centered, because it is. Your actual issue is that your image doesn't have enough height at that size to fill the height of the container.

See the screenshot below, here I have used the element inspector to highlight the "outer-wrapper" which is the blue box you see. Notice the text is centered within it.

[image: Screenshot of outer-wrapper]

So to tackle the actual issue which is the image either needs to fill the div or needs to stay centered itself.

To stay centered add the following to the outer-wrapper: ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/656zw5bc/2/))

```
background-position: center;
```

To fill the div, remove the background-size from outer-wrapper and add this: ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5h37fbs/1/))

```
background-position: center;
background-cover: cover;
```